# Using python variable in HTML to display image

Tags: python, html, image, flask

I am setting up a webserver with flask and seaborn/matplotlib. There I am creating and assigning a variable in Python `img_buffer` of type `IOBytes` to represent a graph.
Then I am transforming this data into an `str img_tag`:

```
...
import base64
str_equivalent_image = base64.b64encode(img_buffer.getvalue()).decode()
img_tag = "<img src='data:image/png;base64," + str_equivalent_image + "'/>"
```

Now I want to use this `img_tag` in the corresponding index.html to display the image. How to I do that? The following did not work:

```
...
<body>
  <h1>Graph</h1>
  {img_tag}
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code I used. It is reduced as much as possible. The page is updated every 0,5s. Later the graphic should be updated as well on the basis of dynamic data I read out from a URL, but this is not yet implemented:

server.py:

```
from gevent import monkey; monkey.patch_all()
from flask import Flask, Response, render_template, stream_with_context, url_for, send_file, render_template
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
import json
import time
import io
import base64
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(6,6))
ax=sns.set(style="darkgrid")

x=[i for i in range(100)]
y=[i for i in range(100)]

app = Flask(__name__)
counter = 100

@app.route("/")
def render_index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/getVisualizeData')
def getVisualizeData():
    sns.lineplot(x,y)
    canvas=FigureCanvas(fig)
    img = io.BytesIO()
    fig.savefig(img)
    img.seek(0)
    return img

@app.route("/listen")
def listen():

    def respond_to_client():
        while True:
            img_buffer=getVisualizeData()
            str_equivalent_image = base64.b64encode(img_buffer.getvalue()).decode()
            img_tag = "<img src='data:image/png;base64," + str_equivalent_image + "'/>"
            _data = json.dumps({"img_tag":img_tag})
            yield f"id: 1\ndata: {_data}\nevent: online\n\n"
            time.sleep(0.5)
    return Response(respond_to_client(), mimetype='text/event-stream')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    http_server = WSGIServer(("localhost", 8080), app)
    http_server.serve_forever()
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>APP</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Graph</h1>
  {img_tag}
  <script>
    var eventSource = new EventSource("/listen")
    eventSource.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
      console.log(e.data)
    }, false)

    eventSource.addEventListener("online", function(e) {
      data = JSON.parse(e.data)
      document.querySelector("#img_tag").innerText = data.img_tag
    }, true)
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is Python serving the file in question? What templating engine are you using which uses the syntax you tried in your HTML? Can you share the code of the server you're running as a [mre]?

Comment: Python is creating the IOBytes using seaborn/matplotlib dynamically every second. And I want to display that image in my browser. For that I am trying to get html to display it.

Comment: Ok, but re-iterating the same thing you mentioned in your original question doesn’t help to answer my clarifying questions above - how is the HTML being *served*? From where did you get the idea that the brackets in your HTML file would magically pull in data from your Python script…?

Comment: I updated my inital post with the source code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using double brackets

```
<body>
    <h1>Graph<h1>
    {{img_tag}}
</body>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. If I look at the final HTML code in the Browser, there is just nothing below the Graph header.